# How does if() work in org spreadsheets?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc, spreadsheet

I got the impression from the manual that

```
    | a |   |
    | b |   |
    #+TBLFM: $2=if($-1==a, 1, 0)
```

should produce "1" in the first row and "0" in the second.  But
instead I get

```
    | a |             1 |
    | b | b = a ? 1 : 0 |
    #+TBLFM: $2=if($-1==a, 1, 0)
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably better off using [Lisp formulas](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp) for things like this. As @db48x's answer points out, there are a couple of cooks in that kitchen and what they are doing is not always obvious. [Formula debugging](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html#Editing-and-debugging-formulas) can help but it is not always effective (I presume that's how @db48x discovered the "(a)" thing, but that may not be the case).

I find the string conversions unpredictable, so for non-numeric things in particular, I tend to stay away from calc formulas and do it in Lisp instead.

In  this particular case, try the following:

```
| a | 1 |
| b | 0 |
#+TBLFM: $2 = '(if (string= $-1 "a") 1 0)
```

The disadvantage(?) is that you have to learn some Lisp, but that's a good thing: otherwise, how are you going to tinker with all those Emacs settings?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what's going on here, but after doing a little debugging I found that this works:

```
| a |   |
| b |   |
#+TBLFM: $2=if("$1"=="(a)", 1, 0)
```

It looks to me like it's doing algebraic simplification in order to get an answer, and if that fails it can be left with a more complicated form than you expected. `b = a ? 1 : 0` is a ternary expression that hasn't been evaluated to a value, presumably because `a` and `b` are treated as variables rather than strings. So you have to put them in quotes, but then "$-1" evaluates to a string with parenthesis for unknown reasons, so you have to include those parentheses on the other side of the equation as well.